# Equivalent of Tuple.Create for Actions and Funcs

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, .net-6.0

A cool thing about `Tuple`s in .NET is that instead of typing:

```cs
var x = new Tuple<string, string, int, float, int>("Hi", "Hello", 15, 5.5f, 500);
```

You can type

```
var x = Tuple.Create("Hi", "Hello", 15, 5.5f, 500);
```

And the correct generic `Tuple` will be created for you.

The same shortcut would be beneficial for `Action`s and `Func`s. Since this doesn't seem to be available for them, how would one implement it, so that instead of typing this:

```cs
var x = new Action<string, float, int>((s, f, i) => { /* do something */ });
```

or even worse, this:

```cs
var x = new Action<string, float, int>((string s, float f, int i) => { /* do something */ });
```

you can type something nice like this:

```cs
var x = Action.Create((string s, float f, int i) => { /* do something */ });
// x becomes an Action<string, float, int>
```

Even though the length is the same, the latter example makes what the parameters are more clear, and it looks neater overall.

How can I implement such an extension method? Note that I'm using .NET 6.0 with C# 10.0

Comment: `static class Action
{
 public static Action<T1,T2,T3> Create<T1,T2,T3>(Action<T1,T2,T3> action) => action;
}` or just `Action<string, float, int> x = (s, f, i) => { /* do something */ };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C# 10, there are "[natural function types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/lambda-improvements#natural-function-type)". You don't even need such a method - just by writing the lambda directly and assign it to a `var`, C# can infer the type of the delegate.

```
var action = (string s, float f, int i) => { ... };
```

Note that this is not necessarily `Action` if you have too many parameters. There are only a finite number of `Action` types, which supports up to a limited number of parameters.

If you really want a method, you can do:

```
var anotherAction = Actions.Create((string s, float f, int i) => { ... });

public static class Actions {
    public static T Create<T>(T t) where T: Delegate => t;
}
```

because natural function types also work when you call a method.

Comment: Just a small extension: sometimes this feature is referred as `inferred delegate type` as well (for example in the [Open Issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/lambda-improvements#open-issues) section). Also if you would like to use it in for instance .NET 5 then you would see an error like this: *Compilation error (line x, col y): Feature 'inferred delegate type' is not available in C# 8.0. Please use language version 10.0 or greater.*

Comment: Or why not `Action<string, float, int> x = (s, f, i) => { /* do something */ };` which works on any recent version

Comment: @Charlieface OP didn't like `var x = new Action<string, float, int>((s, f, i) => { /* do something */ });` so I doubt they would like that either.